# delete columns based on fixed values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete the columns where the non zeros is less than a said number.This is the code I got but it is giving the same answer.What am I doing wrong?

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0]])



   0  1  2  3
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  0

df = df.loc[:, (df.astype(bool).sum(axis=0) <= max_number_of_zeros)]

   0  1  2  3
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  0
```

edit--
example-

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  0  0  0
1  2  0  1  0
2  0  2  3  4
3  1  1  1  1
```

output would be for value=2 the columns 0 and column 2

```
 0  1  2  3
0  1  0  0  0
1  2  0  1  0
2  0  2  3  4
3  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the boolean mask to `df.eq(0)` which is the same as `df == 0` with changed condition from `<=` to `<`:

```
max_number_of_zeros = 2
df  = df.loc[:,df.eq(0).sum(axis=0) < max_number_of_zeros]
print (df)
   0  2
0  1  0
1  2  1
2  0  3
3  1  1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.eq(0))
       0      1      2      3
0  False   True   True   True
1  False   True  False   True
2   True  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False

print (df.eq(0).sum(axis=0))
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

```
max_number_of_zeros = 2
df  = df.loc[:,len(df.columns) - df.astype(bool).sum(axis=0) < max_number_of_zeros]
print (df)
   0  2
0  1  0
1  2  1
2  0  3
3  1  1
```

Comment: shouldnt the answer be col1 and co2 ?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - Sorry, solution was multiple times edited, now it should working nice.

Comment: for no of zeros=2 the df doesnt change

Comment: Yes, it is expected, because want remove columns with more as 2 values of zeros, so it means 3 and more

Comment: I want to remove the columns whch have more than or equal to 2 zeros

Comment: Then change `<=`to < and constant is 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174123/discussion-between-ubuntu-noob-and-jezrael).

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - Sorry, I was offline, check edited answer.

Comment: can this work if I am counting non zero instead of zero?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - Yes, it is possible, only subtract length of columns, check edited answer.